# Showing Syntax error, unexpected variable “$buyValue”

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Showing Syntax error, unexpected variable “$buyValue”
I don't know where I mistake on livewire controller, anyone please help to findout where I mistake here.

```
$marketData = \Http::get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol='.$lists->pair.'USDT')->json()

$buyValue = $lists->size * $lists->entry_price;
$currentvalue = $lists->size*$marketData['lastPrice'];
                                
$profitloss = $currentvalue - $buyValue;
if($price > $lists->entry_price){
 if($lists->order_type == "buy") {
   $lists->profit_loss = $profitloss;
 }else{
   $lists->profit_loss = '-'.$profitloss; 
}else{
 if($lists->order_type == "buy") {
   $profit_loss = $profitloss;
 }else{
   $profit_loss = substr($profitloss, 1); 
   } 
}
```

`

Please help

Answer (score -1):

you have missed semicolon ( ; ) at the end of very first line in script you posted.

```
$marketData = \Http::get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol='.$lists->pair.'USDT')->json()
```

to

```
$marketData = \Http::get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol='.$lists->pair.'USDT')->json();
```